# Semantic UI sidebar component does not retain background color on toggle

Tags: javascript, sidebar, semantic-ui

I'm new to js and jquery but I believe I'm implementing the sidebar correctly. To test it in a clean environment, I copied and pasted the example code directly from the Semantic UI documentation page here:

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html

```
<body>
  <div class="ui sidebar inverted vertical menu">
    <a class="item">1</a>
    <a class="item">2</a>
    <a class="item">3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
    <button class="ui button">Click me</button>
  </div>
</body>


$(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".ui.sidebar").sidebar('toggle')
    });
});
```

When the sidebar is toggled open Semantic changes the body background color to white with a 'dimmer div' on top. It does not retain the background color when the sidebar is toggled closed.

I've tried hacking some overrides onto Semantic, but I can't get it to retain the background color. Semantic changes the background color in two places.

Ideally I'd rather not "hack" Semantic, as I'm copying this code directly from the site and I can't find any other questions about it on Stack Overflow, am I missing something?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/nextuniverse/pen/JKYNXy

Update: Thanks to Ariel's response, I have updated the Codepen to reflect to correct markup and styling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semantic UI has a CSS rule that reads:

```
body.pushable>.pusher {
  background: #fff;
}
```

The `pushable` class is added to `<body>` when the sidebar is shown, thus triggering the background color change to white.

So, to set `<body>`'s background, you have to use `body.pushable > .pusher` selector in your CSS/SASS instead of just `body`. You can try it in the CodePen link you provided.